# How to Clearing/Deleting Webview's Web Storage

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to fix a problem with my app that I bought but anyone give me support, well my problem is that webview load's previously loaded URL when we are saving cookies and maintaining cache etc.now what happens is webview maintains web storage for these loaded pages.In order to load new URL every time we've to clear/delete this web storage.

In others forums told me that I can Implement this in onPause or onDestroy methods in fragments. By calling this methods

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearFormData();
webView.clearHistory();
webView.clearSslPreferences(); 
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null); 
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
```

But I really don't know how to implement them here:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    // try to remove this view from its parent first
    try {
        ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    // then try to remove all child views from this view
    try {
        removeAllViews();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    // and finally destroy this view
    destroy();
}
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was for Javascript but I saw this was actually Java. Please update tag, thanks. Also, please post your final post instead of having answers keep checking your edited version again and again.